# How to remove a command from a Word right-click menu

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office-2021

I've got four commands,Translate, Read Aloud, Link, and New Comment, in the Microsoft Word 2021 text right-click menu that I will never use just wasting space. How can I remove them?
I've found code to add commands and I don't understand it, but it works.
This is how I added the lowercase command to the text right-click. Can something like it remove commands too.

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
 Dim cb As CommandBar
 Dim ctl As CommandBarButton
 On Error GoTo bye
 
 CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
 Set cb = CommandBars("Text")
 Set ctl = cb.FindControl(Tag:="lowerCase")
 If ctl Is Nothing Then
  Set ctl = cb.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, _
  Before:=9, Temporary:=True)
  
  With ctl
 .Caption = "lower Case"
 .Tag = "lower Case"
 .FaceId = 947
 .OnAction = "lowerCase"
  End With
 End If
bye:
End Sub
```

Comment: For more on this, see Greg Maxey's page on the subject. http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you can use Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to customize the context menu in Microsoft Word. Here's an example of how you can use VBA to remove the "Translate," "Read Aloud," "Link," and "New Comment" commands from the text right-click menu:

Open Microsoft Word and press "Alt + F11" to open the VBA editor.

In the VBA editor, click on "Insert" in the top menu and then choose "Module" to insert a new module.

Copy and paste the following VBA code into the module window:

```
Sub RemoveCommandsFromContextMenu()
    ' Remove "Translate" command
    CommandBars("Text").Controls("Translate").Delete
    
    ' Remove "Read Aloud" command
    CommandBars("Text").Controls("Speak").Delete
    
    ' Remove "Link" command
    CommandBars("Text").Controls("Hyperlink").Delete
    
    ' Remove "New Comment" command
    CommandBars("Text").Controls("NewComment").Delete

End Sub
```

Close the VBA editor by clicking the "X" button in the top-right corner or pressing "Alt + Q."

Press "Alt + F8" to open the "Macro" dialog box.

Select "RemoveCommandsFromContextMenu" from the list of macros and click "Run."

The VBA code provided above will remove the "Translate," "Read Aloud," "Link," and "New Comment" commands from the right-click context menu in Microsoft Word.

Additionally, Microsoft may change its software or features in future updates, so the information provided here may become outdated or subject to change.

Comment: Thank you 
The first time I ran it, it didn’t do anything. I changed the wording of the commands in the parenthesis following .Controls() to exactly how they are worded in the right-click menu, including an (&) in front of the letter underlined in the menu. 
This only removed the top two commands, “Translate” and “Read Aloud.”
I’m thrilled as it removes the two commands I would never use.
The last two commands, “Link” and “New Comment”, I wonder if their position at the bottom in their own group right below the “Save” command I added with VBA is the reason I can’t remove them.